# Parse through "USE" column of my ASB server list

Tags: excel, parsing

I am working with a server list and I need to know how to create a string to parse through the "USE" column of the server list.

Comment: Hi @Cryptol, please provide some additional details. What does your excel file currently look like? What do you want the outcome to look like?

Comment: Hello @JoshJay. My excel file file is a basic excel CSV file with columns listed as such: Type (Computer), DSPS (Application Server), Security Boundary (Authorization Boundary). I want to be able to create a string to parse through the "USE" column of the Server list. Most likely through VBA in excel. Thanks.

Comment: it sounds like you just want to concatenate some text for each row in order to create statements? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I need to create a syntax that will then be converted into a string that will help me parse through a column in my spread sheet that has a list of AD servers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas:

### 1) If it's a one-time manipulation of data

Import the data into Excel, then use the `CONCATENATE` function ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d)) or the `&` operator to combine text values into the appropriate format.

```
=CONCATENATE("USE ", A1, " BLAH BLAH BLAH", B1)
```

or

```
="USE "&A1&" BLAH BLAH BLAH"&B1
```

### 2) If it's a recurring need

Use the [Power Query CSV connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/textcsv) to ingest the CSV file and add a concatenation formula in Power Query ([Text.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-combine)) or the resulting table (same formulas as above).

If the filename changes with each extract, use the [Import Data from a folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4) feature.

Drop the new files in the same folder then just refresh the data and the list will be updated automatically.

Comment: Will this allow me to parse the column that I am trying to, by using the string manipulation process. This will be recurring data that will update overtime.

Comment: @CryptoL, this would be to generate statements to copy and apply elsewhere. If you want to automate queries against a system, you'd likely need to use VBA or depending on the system and use case, Power Query.

Comment: How would I use the Concatenate function to verify what data is linked to other data in a Excel spread sheet.